# how to wait a second before function execution

Tags: javascript, html, timer

how to make this js function be executed after one second of touching the screen
and
how can i make it a one second of the same touch position..if i keep touching the screen in the same position for one second?

```
function onCanvasTouchStart(event)
{
    if(event.touches.length == 1)
    {
        // draw
        event.preventDefault();
        brush.strokeStart((event.touches[0].pageX) - canvas.offsetLeft, (event.touches[0].pageY) - canvas.offsetTop);
        window.addEventListener('touchmove', onCanvasTouchMove, false);
        window.addEventListener('touchend', onCanvasTouchEnd, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [setTimeOut](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

```
function onCanvasTouchStart( event ){
    if(event.touches.length == 1){
        setTimeout(function(){ 
           // draw
           event.preventDefault();

           brush.strokeStart( (event.touches[0].pageX) - canvas.offsetLeft, (event.touches[0].pageY) - canvas.offsetTop );

           window.addEventListener('touchmove', onCanvasTouchMove, false);
           window.addEventListener('touchend', onCanvasTouchEnd, false); 
        }, 1000);

    }

}
```

Comment: how can i make it a one second of the same touch position..if i keep touching the screen in the same position for one second?

Comment: Like @ManoDestra said, you need to track the touch start/end time. I have roughly put some code to demonstrate the idea in this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/keL9pbar/ .

Answer (score 1):

```
function onCanvasTouchStart(event) {
    if (event.touches.length == 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // draw
            event.preventDefault();

            brush.strokeStart( (event.touches[0].pageX) - canvas.offsetLeft, (event.touches[0].pageY) - canvas.offsetTop );

            window.addEventListener('touchmove', onCanvasTouchMove, false);
            window.addEventListener('touchend', onCanvasTouchEnd, false);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

This will occur after any touch to the screen a second later, but if you need it after a continuous 1 second touch on the screen, then you'll need to ensure that the touch wasn't ended at any point prior to this inner function being called. You could store the Date at which a touch starts/ends. And if any touch end occurred since the touch started that signalled this setTimeout, you would not continue with the inner function's code.

Comment: how can i make it a one second of the same touch position..if i keep touching the screen in the same position for one second?

Comment: You'll have to ensure that any touch move events do not take you too far from a delta average in that case. So that their finger has stayed SUFFICIENTLY still. Or just make sure no move events have occurred since the start, if you want to be strict on it.